# Are there binary packages available to upgrade python3 on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, python

I need to upgrade Python on 30 laptops at several remote sites. These laptops have Debian 9 with Python 3.5, and the library they'll be using for the planned activity (arcade) requires Python 3.6.

I have an update process that can deploy package updates, but it needs to be able to install quickly, so compiling Python is not an option.

Comment: would 3.7 work?

Comment: Yeah, Pyhton3.7 would work

Comment: So if you absolutely cannot install it from source your options are to grab a random packaged binary off of github or upgrade to Buster to get 3.7 from the repos. If you have the infrastructure to deliver a package to other computers you only need to compile and package python once and deliver it that way. If you could edit your post to include more details as to what your available resources are I could assist in making an answer for that or provide details on how to migrate to Buster.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up compiling python on an identical target machine using `--prefix=/opt/Python3.6` as a configure option. I then just zipped up that dir so the target machines could download and extract it during the update process. The users were instructed to use `/opt/Python3.6/bin/python3` as the interpreter.